# Energy of a signal contained within a given band

Tags: time-series, discrete-data, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis

Suppose I wish to compute the energy contained in a given frequency range using FFT. So, first, I compute FFT and take the squares of the absolute values of $x_k$. Can I then use discrete integration over the frequency range of interest, or there are some more specific schemes?

Can I improve the result by using zero-padding? If so, are there some rules regarding the optimal choice of padding interval?

Comment: I think that you can sum the values of the $|x_{k}|^2$ multiplied by the frequency bin width, $\Delta f$. As for zero-padding, I can be more confident: if you are multiplying in the frequency domain ($x_{k} \cdot x_{k}^{*}$ in the case of the spectrum / energy) then you should always zero-pad. The reason is that multiplication in the frequency domain is convolution in the time domain. Without the zero-padding, calculations are being carried out as if the first and last values of the time series are adjacent to each other (i.e., at lag-1).

Comment: Great, thanks! But $|x_k|^2=x_k\cdot x_k^*$. So, if I understand you correctly, zero-padding is a must. Are there any rules to choose the interval of zero-padding depending on the number of elements in the sample?

Comment: Apologies! I should have mentioned that. You want the zero-padded length of your series to be at least twice the length of the original series. This avoids the circular autocorrelation issue. Depending on the FFT, they can be most efficient when the zero-padded series length can be factored into small primes, so I will often choose a zero-padded series length that is: $M = 2^{\lfloor \log_{2}(n) \rfloor + 2}$, and therefore add $M - n$ zeros at the end (where $n$ is the original length of the series).